# Bluetooth not working on Lenovo G Series

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, 64-bit, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo laptop  has suddenly stopped letting me use Bluetooth to transfer data from my phone.
Every time I have to reinstall the device drivers of Bluetooth from devmgmt to be able to use it again.

It gets nasty once done as the device driver as takes at-least takes 2-3 reboots to be able to get the drivers back up.

Please help me with a solution.

OS : Windows 8.1 64 bit

Please let me know if you need any specific details about my laptop to be able to help me in sorting this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this types of problems happens due to aborted upadation or curruption of setup files while installing other drivers and softwares.
so try to insatll latest driver.
1st unistall/delete existing bluetooth driver and install latest bluetooth driver from http://support.lenovo.com/in/hi/
you can download newest drivers of your laptop from this site.